# Why proguard processes AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, optimization, broadcastreceiver, proguard

I see some unexplained Proguard behaviour.

AFAIK proguard does not pay attention to android manifest. Also, in my proguard.cfg I have no mention of BroadcastReceiver related classes. So I assume that those should be stripped out.

However I see something strange in bin/proguard.txt:

```
# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:784
-keep class com.fiksu.asotracking.InstallTracking { <init>(...); }
```

and that class (descendand of BroadcastReceiver) does not get stripped. Reason does not say anything meaningful to me:

```
[proguard] com.fiksu.asotracking.InstallTracking
[proguard]   is kept by a directive in the configuration.
```

If class is not mentioned in manifest, it gets stripped.

Would be great to know why.

Comment: Have you checked `<path-to-your-sdk>/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt`. That usually contains the declarations that prevents Proguard from completely murdering your application.

Comment: Yep, to my understanding it does not contain anything related to BroadcastReceivers or manifest, or I interpret it wrongly.

Comment: The sdk definition usually contains something like this: `-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver` that prevents receivers from being mangled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The build process runs the tool `aapt` to automatically create the configuration file `bin/proguard.txt`, based on `AndroidManifest.xml` and other xml files. The build process then passes the configuration file to ProGuard. So ProGuard itself indeed doesn't consider `AndroidManifest.xml`, but aapt+ProGuard do.

Comment: Thanks, Eric! Does it also mean that we do not need anymore to manually add "keep" directives for broadcast receivers, services and so on?

Comment: @Stipa That's correct. The default configuration inside the SDK should provide all generic settings, and aapt should create all application-specific configuration (except application-specific reflection).