# Why Proguard keeps Activity class in Android?

Tags: android, proguard

I have applied **ProGuard** to my Android application.

I'm using

```
android-studio/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
```

as a configuration file, changing nothing.

In this file I can see the only statement regarding **Activity**:

```
We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
```

It follows from that the **Activities** class names are obfusctated by ProGuard while some methods are preserved as they are. This is understandable.

However, in my application I then create an Activity Class from a string using

```
Class.forName("my.app.MyActivity")
```

then I start this Activity and it starts fine.

**But that means Activity-derived classes are not obfuscated??**. It should have failed because ProGuard does not have `-keep class` directive for `Activity`, it only has `-keepclassmembers.`

Can someone, please, explain, if I can rely on the behaviour I observe? Or do I misunderstand the `-keepclassmembers` directive?

Comment: You should post the whole file, because that line alone isn't enough to explain why it keeps the Activity name

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the activities are listed in the manifest and classes referenced there are automagically kept. This is needed because the Android framework accesses these app entry points via reflection.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180434/why-proguard-processes-androidmanifest-xml):

> The build process runs the tool aapt to automatically create the configuration file `bin/proguard.txt`, based on `AndroidManifest.xml` and other xml files. The build process then passes the configuration file to ProGuard. So ProGuard itself indeed doesn't consider `AndroidManifest.xml`, but aapt+ProGuard do.

Answer (score 4):

From the [ProGuard FAQ](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#FAQ.html):

> Does ProGuard handle Class.forName calls?
>
> Yes. ProGuard automatically handles constructs like Class.forName("SomeClass") and SomeClass.class. The referenced classes are preserved in the shrinking phase, and the string arguments are properly replaced in the obfuscation phase.
> With variable string arguments, it's generally not possible to determine their possible values. They might be read from a configuration file, for instance. However, ProGuard will note a number of constructs like "(SomeClass)Class.forName(variable).newInstance()". These might be an indication that the class or interface SomeClass and/or its implementations may need to be preserved. The developer can adapt his configuration accordingly.

So, ProGuard's being cleverer than you expected: it will automatically detect and handle simple cases of the use for `forName()`. Even if the class isn't referenced in the Android manifest file, ProGuard will obfuscate the class name in both the class *and* in your call to `forName()`.

For Activities, it wouldn't surprise me if you're doubly-covered by both this behaviour and by the Android-specific input to ProGuard that's part of the build process, as @laalto mentions in his answer.