# ProGuard Still Displays Full Activity Name

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am using Proguard and in my app I use this code

```
            System.out.println("ACTIVITY NAME IS " + activity.getLocalClassName());
```

It prints out the Activity name out, Iin release mode.  I thought it is suppose to obfuscate all class names?

Is this behavior normal?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Proguard keeps Activity class in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619955/why-proguard-keeps-activity-class-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is a normal behaviour. Activity names are never obfuscated because these are referenced in manifest.xml. and android access these activities via reflection so their names cannot be changed. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/20620108/1320616

Comment: Oh Thanks, Is there a way to check if the code has been successfully obfuscated?

Comment: I use to check it using online decompilers like http://www.decompileandroid.com/ upload the apk there and get back the decompiled folder. There it can be checked whether the code is obfuscated or not.

Comment: You can also use Analyse APK option in Android Studio to find whether you are able to se your code after generating apk.