# Is there any documentation stating that activity cannot be obfuscated?

Tags: android, proguard

I need an official documentation of Android or Proguard stating that activity cannot be obfuscated mentioning with the reason. I tried to search online even gone through Proguard documentation but didn't find anything regarding this. Please help me if possible

Official Documentation

Comment: Try check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20620112/22006294.

Comment: There is no reason why you should not be able to obfuscate activities, however Proguard simply does not support this type of obfuscation.