# Is ProGuard really a good way to protect the android application?

Tags: android

Is ProGuard  really  a good way to protect the android application? I do not think. Please see the following images:

**Compile Code**

[image]

**Decompile_Code**

[image]

Also the variable names did not change and the code is readable easily.

Comment: The ProGuard rules for an Android project `-keep` all activities. Otherwise, we could not create instances of those activities via reflection based on manifest entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activity classes are not completely obfuscated. This is because the activities are listed in the manifest and classes referenced there are automagically kept. This is needed because the Android framework accesses these app entry points via reflection.

Read more from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180434/why-proguard-processes-androidmanifest-xml):

> The build process runs the tool aapt to automatically create the
>   configuration file bin/proguard.txt, based on AndroidManifest.xml and
>   other xml files. The build process then passes the configuration file
>   to ProGuard. So ProGuard itself indeed doesn't consider
>   AndroidManifest.xml, but aapt+ProGuard do.