# Proguard not working ,eclipse(android) not Obfuscation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

The problem is Obfuscation using the latest version of Proguard5.3.2 toll.
My computer environment is build, eclipse, android 22 and java level 1.6.
After using the Proguard toll,
the files of dump.txt , mapping.txt ,seeds.txt and usage.txt is created.

However, the Obfuscation do not apply to apk generated by an export signed Android application.
Please let me know what I wrongly applied to source.

I attached full [source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ir1y8xea28l9uj/KeyEvent.7z?dl=0)( https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ir1y8xea28l9uj/KeyEvent.7z?dl=0 )
about simple key event.
Option is Default options(tool>proguard>proguard-android.txt) and I did not change anything

Thank you for your kind cooperation in advance and I look forward to hearing from you soon.

simple step

1 project.properties add proguard path

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

proguard-android.txt android default setting don't edit

2 update proguard

```
proguard 5.3.2
```

3 made proguard folder and file

```
dump.txt , mapping.txt ,seeds.txt ,usage.txt
```

4 export singned Android application

```
no error , made singned apk
```

5 output apk -> decomplie but not obfuscating
mapping.txt

```
com.superdroid.test.event.key.MainActivity -> 
com.superdroid.test.event.key.MainActivity:
long mExitModeTime -> a
```

decomple apk source

```
MainActivity.class not change (mExitModeTime -> a)
private long mExitModeTime = 0L;
```

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard doesn't obfuscate classes that extend from `Activity`, as mentioned in Eric LaFortune's (original author of ProGuard) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180434/why-proguard-processes-androidmanifest-xml).

You can find a complete list of the Java classes that were obfuscated by checking the `usage.txt` file while classes that were left unchanged are listed in `seeds.txt`.

Comment: ok thanks your comment so I option change (proguard-android.txt) keep **  all block. 
proguard-android.txt has options -dontusemixedcaseclassnames ,-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses ,-dontwarn android.support.**
-verbose,-dontoptimize ,-dontpreverify-dontshrink #(this option not make usage.txt) but not working .. my seeds.txt 

The resource file did not exist. That is, changed it 
I expected the resource file to change. 
mapping.txt find     int activity_horizontal_margin -> a   
but not Obfuscation

Comment: ` int activity_horizontal_margin -> a` means that `activity_horizontal_margin` was obfuscated and it's now called `a`, so it worked as planned. You definitely don't want a `-dontshrink` directive, which would make ProGuard skip one of its crucial steps.

Comment: I was using the Android studio and was successful with the same options same settings. but eclipse not working ...  
I'll just use the studio.

Answer (score 0):

I am worried that what you are actually trying to do is to save a password or some other static field like a string or int that you don't want  to be retrievable from the apk. Unfortunately, you cannot do that. To my knowledge, constants will always be there somewhere in the apk, even if you don't put it in an activity. If there is some protected content, like a password, then you should not hard code it. You must have another pattern to get that into the code, like having the user enter it.

Comment: Thanks your opinion I just want to see folder names or variable names obfuscated.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. The wording sounded to me like you wanted to hide the values, and I have seen that mistake far too many times.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to obfuscate all Activity classes and all strings (like key, password,...) you can try a alternative solution: [Bg+ Anti Decompiler/Obfuscator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bgplus.Anti.JavaDecompiler)

[Obfuscated sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWHDH.png)

```
public class l000001 extends Activity {
static int ß¤¤=0,ß¤¥=0,ß¤ª=0;
static List ß¤º=null;
static int[] ß¤Þ=null;
void ¢¢£() {
   ¢¢ = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
   ¢¢¢=null;
   {
      AdRequest ¢¢¤ = new AdRequest.Builder() .build();
      ¢¢.loadAd(¢¢¤);
      ¢¢º();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please use standard coding syntax when posting a code snippet to help readability for others